# IoC, Mixing injections with parameters in the constructor?

Tags: inversion-of-control

I am new to [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC), so I wanted to know the best strategy to handle
the case where I want to pass data structures/parameters as well as injected
objects into a class.

A simple example:

```
public class EmailSender
{

    public EmailSender(string toEmail, string Subject, String body,
                       ILogger emailLogger)
    {.....}
}
```

What is the best strategy here? I guess it's not possible to inject directly?

I guess I need to put all the string parameters as setters instead and
just have the `Ilogger` in the constructor, or the other way around?

Or am I wrong?

P.s. I know the example above sucks and `toEmail` and `body` should be passed in a separate method call, but it was just to make an example.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should be able to specify the strings in the constructor call. Admittedly I'd usually expect those to be more "transient" values passed in as method arguments:

```
public class EmailSender
{
    private readonly ILogger emailLogger;

    public EmailSender(ILogger emailLogger)
    {
         this.emailLogger = emailLogger;
    }

    public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

That way the same `EmailSender` can be used to send many emails - the details of the email itself "flow through" the sender rather than being part of it.

EDIT: Given the edit to the question, it's not entirely clear what remains. If you're really asking how to specify strings as constructor arguments, that will depend on the IoC framework you're using. If you could specify the framework, we could probably give you the appropriate syntax.